# update and set initial values to react hook form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, react-hook-form

i'm new in react/typescript and Chakra UI. I have the following issue

here i get the current object to be updated:

```ts
const {
  data: judicialCause,
  isLoading,
  error,
  updateJudicialCause,
} = useJudicialCause(parseInt(id!));
const {
  register,
  control,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors, isValid },
  setValue,
  reset,
  watch,
} = useForm<FormData>({ values: judicialCause, resolver: zodResolver(schema) });
const { data: caseTypes } = useCaseTypes();
```

the interface

```ts
export default {
  id: number,
  //....,
  case_type: number[]
}
```

and finally the trouble. I want to render all possible values for caseTypes and set the ones which are selected in the current judicialCause object. This objects has the related causes as a number array. Example ->

```ts
case_type: [2,4,5]
```

```tsx
<CheckboxGroup colorScheme="green">
  {caseTypes?.results.map((ct, index) => (
    <Checkbox key={ct.id} {...register(`case_type.${index}`)}>
      {ct.name}
    </Checkbox>
  ))}
</CheckboxGroup>
```

how could i show the selected values for that object?

Thanks!

i tried using `useFieldArray`, but it doesn't work because it's not for values array.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider `defaultChecked` inside the `Checkbox`.

[Chakra Ui Checkbox](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/checkbox/usage)

```js
<CheckboxGroup colorScheme="green">
  {caseTypes?.results.map((ct, index) => (
   <Checkbox
       key={ct.id}
       {...register(`case_type.${index}`)}
       defaultChecked={judicialCause?.case_type?.includes(ct.id)}
   >
     {ct.name}
   </Checkbox>
  ))}
</CheckboxGroup>
```

Check whether `caseTypes` are included in the `case_type` of `judicialCause`. I've added the optional chaining operator `?.` to increase safety.